# How do you setup an offline Chocolatey instance?

Tags: chocolatey

My company has a disconnected network that is used for development. I enjoy using Chocolatey at home, and would like to setup a similar instance at work. From what I have read, I need to setup a Nu-get server, but is there a good way to get all of the packages imported?

Comment: Have a look http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds and http://www.adamjamesnaylor.com/2013/04/26/Setting-Up-A-Private-NuGet-Server.aspx

Comment: The main "issue" that you are going to have is that although you can add the Chocolatey packages to your own, internal nuget server, the contents of those packages will still look to the internet to download the msi/exes. If you want to host them locally, you will need to modify the download link in each package. There is a tool that claims to help with this: https://github.com/BahKoo/ChocolateStore but I haven't had a chance to try this out yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a normal usage of Chocolatey, completely disconnected. Most companies set up their own servers (as you have noted) and make their own packages or pull in and change packages to look at local resources instead of the internet.

We are going to be getting better at making Chocolatey proper able to handle this. The process of taking an existing package and editing it so that it is completely offline is what we call internalizing - see https://chocolatey.org/docs/how-to-recompile-packages. And Chocolatey for Business offers Package Internalizer - https://chocolatey.org/docs/features-automatically-recompile-packages