# PowerShell / Chocolatey, how to do an offline install of Chocolatey itself

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

I would like to get chocolatey onto multiple systems. The normal way I do this is:

```
if (!(Test-Path "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin")) {
    Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
}
```

That's fine, but this will connect to the internet, pointlessly re-downloading the Chocolatey package that I should be able to keep pre-downloaded, then extracting and setting up Chocolatey. This is like having to download a `setup.exe` every single time that you just want to install a program (for 20 systems, you would then have to download `setup.exe` 20 times), which slows things down and feels wasteful when I just want to get the `choco.exe` command available on systems as quickly as possible. I also don't mind if I have a slightly older version of chocolatey, I can redownload the main copy whenever I need.

It occurs to me that it should be easy to have the components pre-downloaded, so that I can just point at those files:

- What files do we need to pre-download to have everything required to setup Chocolatey?
- What command would we run against those files to set it up?

Note that this is quite a different question from [How do you setup an offline Chocolatey instance?](https://superuser.com/questions/855081/how-do-you-setup-an-offline-chocolatey-instance)

Comment: Looks like they list all this here: https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/choco/setup#completely-offline-install does that help? There is a full PowerShell script there with more than just the download part.

Comment: Thanks, good find, but sadly, that's not it from what I can see; looking through that code, it's still downloading the setup package from the internet as part of the install process, it seems more about deleting online sources after install? I do want the end result to be a normal chocolatey install that can access internet sources, I just don't want to have to download the chocolatey packages on each and every install, as it's wasteful / pointless. I want to do this on fresh VM's, and this downloading at every install is wasteful and slow when I could install more quickly from a local setup).

Comment: I gotcha, reading through the code is just trivial but it should have the install piece in it you might have to copy out and do testing with to get it. I'll read over it some more, but it download a zip file—which you can store offline/not across Internet/internal network. See https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/choco/setup#completely-offline-install and https://community.chocolatey.org/api/v2/package/chocolatey for some more starting points. I don't have time to poke through it, but it should be possible. Not sure about prerequisites, check those too and automate those for offline install too.

Comment: I think there is something in there from the page you sent, though I have to try it out - this section lower down. I think that might work, have to test it. https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/choco/setup#install-downloaded-nuget-package-from-powershell

Answer (score 0):

Installing Chocolatey offline is pretty simple, these days!

You'll need two files:

- The Chocolatey nupkg (available from the [Chocolatey Community Repository](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/chocolatey), you can hit the download button on the left hand side)
- The [install script](https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1) that you are using above

By default, the script downloads the latest version of Chocolatey from the Chocolatey Community Repository.

It's not clear from the parameter name, but you *can* provide a local file path to use with the `-ChocolateyDownloadUrl` parameter (or by setting `$env:chocolateyDownloadUrl` before running the script).

The command(s) to run to install from local files:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force
.\Install.ps1 -ChocolateyDownloadUrl ~\Path\To\Chocolatey.nupkg
```